# How to get Core Data object instance which has relations?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

In my model I have three entities with the following attributes:

*HumanTask* { idHumanTask, name, outcomes, status, description }

*Outcomes* { idOutcome, label, paramsOutcome }

*ParamsOutcome* { value, xPath }

As you can see HumanTask is an entity that has an attribute of type Outcomes which in turn has an attribute of type ParamsOutcome. What I need is to retrieve a HumanTask instance from its idHumanTask. Then I put the code I use:

```
- (NSDictionary *)findHumanTaskByID:(NSString *)idHumanTask {

    NSArray *requiredFields = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               @"idHumanTask", @"name", @"outcomes", @"status", @"description", nil];

    NSPredicate *queryPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"idHumanTask == %@",idHumanTask];

    NSArray *result = [self.entityManager queryEntity: self.entityName
                                            forFields: requiredFields
                                        withPredicate: queryPredicate
                                           andOrderBy: nil
                                            inContext: self.context
                                        andResultType: NSDictionaryResultType];

    return ([result count] > 0 ? [result objectAtIndex:0] : nil);
}


- (NSArray *)queryEntity: (NSString *)entityName
               forFields: (NSArray*)fieldsRequired
           withPredicate: (NSPredicate *)queryPredicate
              andOrderBy: (NSArray*)sortDescriptors
               inContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *)context
           andResultType: (NSFetchRequestResultType)resultType {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    [request setResultType:resultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];

    if (queryPredicate) {
        [request setPredicate:queryPredicate];
    } 

    if (fieldsRequired) {
        request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
        [request setPropertiesToFetch:fieldsRequired];
    } 

    if (sortDescriptors) {
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    } 

    __block NSArray *result = nil;

    void (^doSearch)(void) = ^{

        NSError *error = nil;

        result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

        if (error != nil) {

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    };

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {

        doSearch();

    } else {

        [context performBlockAndWait:doSearch];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Below the error description I see in console:

**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid to many relationship
>   ((), name outcomes, isOptional
>   1, isTransient 0, entity HumanTask, renamingIdentifier outcomes,
>   validation predicates ( ), warnings ( ), versionHashModifier (null) 
>   userInfo { }, destination entity Outcome, inverseRelationship
>   humanTask, minCount 0, maxCount 0, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1) passed
>   to setPropertiesToFetch::'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x32b782a3 0x3aa0e97f 0x32918da1 0x32917ce5 0x32980d4f 0x329814d9 0x3ae254b7 0x3ae299f7 0x32971df7
>   0x329811cb 0x32917f17 0x8048b 0x80379 0x83d21 0x7346d 0x349cb54d
>   0x349b0313 0x349c77cf 0x34983803 0x3472dd8b 0x3472d929 0x3475c7cf
>   0x34a2d0e9 0x34a2c2d5 0x34a2b4a7 0x34a2b431 0x34b61309 0x349e9691
>   0x349e93d5 0x349e8d3b 0x349dfeab 0x349dbaed 0x34a1d1e9 0xa70c7
>   0x349e0ad9 0x349e0663 0x349d884b 0x34980c39 0x349806cd 0xfdbbb
>   0x3498011b 0x366745a3 0x366741d3 0x32b4d173 0x32b4d117 0x32b4bf99
>   0x32abeebd 0x32abed49 0x349d7485 0x349d4301 0x48505 0x48488)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of `setPropertiesToFetch:`:

> The property descriptions may represent attributes, **to-one relationships**, or expressions.

Your "outcomes" property is a **to-many relationship**, and therefore cannot be used here.

If you need the related *Outcome* objects, you have to execute a "simple" fetch request 
(without `NSDictionaryResultType` or `setPropertiesToFetch`). That returns an array of 
*HumanTask* objects, from which you can get the related *Outcome* objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your Core Data Managed Object Model, are your entities correctly being set up ?

I mean, Does HumanTask have a one-to-many relationship to Outcomes and Outcomes a one-to-many relationship to ParamsOutcome and the `NSManagedObject`s are properly configured (best way of configuring them is delete all your `NSManagedObject` classes for your entities, select the entities in your core data model and press Cmd+N with your entities selected in the model - xcode will automatically create the classes for you) ?

Try first and retrieve a simple batch of objects. You can use this function (I always create a singleton that handles Core Data operations :

```
+ (NSArray*) fetchEntity: (NSString*) entityName withPredicate: (NSPredicate*) predicate andSortDescriptors: (NSArray*) sortDescriptors inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
    [request setEntity: entity];
    if (predicate)
        [request setPredicate: predicate];
    if (sortDescriptors)
        [request setSortDescriptors: sortDescriptors];
    NSArray *resultArray = nil;
    NSError *error;
    resultArray = [context executeFetchRequest: request error:&error];

    if (resultArray == nil)
        resultArray = [NSArray array];
    return resultArray;
}

    NSArray * humanTasks = [CoreData fetchEntity:NSStringFromClass([HumanTask class]) withPredicate:nil andSortDescriptors:nil inContext:yourManagedObjectContext];
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course! All relationships are established between the entities.

Comment: what I suggest is retrieving the objects at a time (first a batch of HumanTasks, then Outcomes and then ParamsOutcome). See if that works first. Then move down to the relationships and try to debug which relationship is causing the problem.